# Trying to rotate about a point, but lose precision no matter what

Tags: java, android, trigonometry

Im trying to make some objects (represented by points) rotate around a fixed point, but while they rotate, they get closer and closer to the point of rotation. Here is a screenshot taken early of the rotating triangles:

[image]

and here is a shot taken moments later

[image]

As you can tell the distance from the center is shortened as well as their distance from each other. Here is the code I'm using to rotate the points about a another point:

```
public void rotateAboutPoint(double x, double y, double angleRad){
    for(int i = 0; i<rep.size(); i++){
        rep.get(i).x = (Math.cos(angleRad) * (rep.get(i).x - x) - Math.sin(angleRad)*(rep.get(i).y - y) + x);
        rep.get(i).y = (Math.sin(angleRad) * (rep.get(i).x - x) + Math.cos(angleRad)*(rep.get(i).y - y) + y);
    }}
```

I used the same algorithm used [here](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2012/11/24/GameDev-math-recipes-Rotating-one-point-around-another-point.aspx). Everything works fine except the objects shrink. I've tried using more precise types, which doesn't help. I've tried wrapping the expressions with Math.Round() to see if that would help by rounding up when necessary. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The value of `rep.get(i).x` you need for the second formula should be the original value, not the new value. Just use a temporary variable. I think this should work.

```
public void rotateAboutPoint(double x, double y, double angleRad){
    for(int i = 0; i<rep.size(); i++){
        double temp = (Math.cos(angleRad) * (rep.get(i).x - x) - Math.sin(angleRad)*(rep.get(i).y - y) + x);
        rep.get(i).y = (Math.sin(angleRad) * (rep.get(i).x - x) + Math.cos(angleRad)*(rep.get(i).y - y) + y);
        rep.get(i).x = temp;
    }}
```

Comment: That sure did it! But why is this only necessary for the x?

Comment: Think about a swap. If you want to swap two values `x` and `y`, you only need one extra variable. `temp = y; y = x; x = temp;`. It's just like that but with trigonometry!